# What percentage is equal to almost all?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

If you use the term "almost all" in a sentence what percentage would you attribute to that?

Example 1:  Dan at almost all of the pie.  Mary had the rest.

Example 2: Almost all kids who go to college have student loans.

Just looking for expectations and an estimate.  If I knew that Dan ate 90% of the pie I would just say that, but I see he at almost all of the pie but not sure the exact percentage.  When I say almost all what would people think?

Comment: A percentage is (quite) exact. "Almost all" is not exact, so there is no way to transform it to a percentage.

Comment: I wouldn't.  Percentages are used for precision.

Comment: I am not looking for a defined percentage.  I am thinking what are the expectations (estimate) when saying it.

Comment: More than 50 and less than 100.

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 - wouldn't that define "most".

Comment: Although this is a language question, it is not linguistic proper, but rather philosophical.

Comment: @TaliaFord - No no no.  I want to know what it means.  More data that backs an answer the better.  Not looking for a philosophy discussion.

Comment: 99.98726%, approximately.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in mathematics and some sciences, *almost all* has a specific technical meaning as discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all).

In common parlance, there is no set definition. Most people would not consider slightly more than half as *almost all*. Somewhere north of 75% is probably what could be considered applicable. Many might not consider it correct unless the amounts were over 90% (although politicians and others who wish to shade the report of support toward their decision might claim 50.01% is *almost all*).

Comment: Re *almost all*, also see the latter half of [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/116164/11433) to a "[Similar numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116141/similar-numbers)" question

Comment: @jwpat7 Excellent complement. Not being knowledgeable about the technical stuff, I was loathe to summarize or select excerpts.

Comment: @bib Many might consider your answer somewhat recursive, as it remains almost totally indeterminable what percentages of people are denoted by the "most people" and "many might".

Comment: @TaliaFord *Most people* is exactly 59.7% and *many might* is 66.2%. I didn't want to show off. Actually, the problem is as indicated in the reason for conrnbread ninja's hold. This is very squooshy and is largley opinion based.